# Save Link as not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

When i try to save some file from website(site is an intranet site and the file is in a network path not in internet) it's not fetching the target file in chrome instead it's getting download.htm. the same intranet site is working fine in IE there we can use Save Target As.

Is there any fix available for that issue??

I want same functionalities as IE "Save Target As"

Please suggest the fix or any Alternative Plugins

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMjOf.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the website and the file you want to download?

Comment: any pdf or any link which points to a file

Comment: Are you using any proxy? Have you tried with another computer with Chrome in your same environment? Have you tried with your same computer in another environment?

Comment: yes but the file is mapped by network path not an internet URL

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome it's called "Save link as..." (available via the right-click)

[image]

Another option:

Test if the "Save As" feature works in Chrome Incognito Mode?
If that doesn't work then try creating a "new browser profile".

Also

As a workaround use the http:// prefix to the UNC path.
Example below:

```
http://Server_Name/FolderName/myDocument.doc
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51730/discussion-on-answer-by-shafiq-save-link-as-not-working-in-chrome).